# Use same alias for union query SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I came across a problem/question yesterday. 
I am building a chat (with AJAX) and use two tables:

`TABLE users -> 'name', 'username', 'password', 'time'` 
`TABLE messages -> 'sendFrom', 'sendTo', 'message', 'time'`

So an example message now would be 
`'foo' | 'bar' | 'Hey, how are you?' | 130611134427611`

I was told the correct way to do this is, instead, to use an `ID` column, and use that as a Primary Key instead of the username (which, anyway, makes sense).

OK, so now this looks like 
`TABLE users -> 'ID', 'name', 'username', 'password', 'time'` 
`TABLE messages -> 'sendFrom', 'sendTo', 'message', 'time'`

So an example message now would be 
`'22' | '7' | 'Hey, how are you?' | 130611134427611`

I've managed to `JOIN` both tables to return the rows as on the first example message, but since I am detecting user keypresses too, I need to scan the table twice, so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM (SELECT * 
            FROM messages 
            WHERE sendTo = '$username'
              AND time > (SELECT time FROM users 
                          WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1)
              AND message <> '$keypressCode' 
            ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 30) 
      ORDER BY time ASC) 
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM messages 
      WHERE message = '$keypressCode'
        AND time > (SELECT time FROM users 
                    WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1)
        AND sendTo = '$username' LIMIT 1);
```

But now, of course, I don't just select from messages; instead, I use a long query like

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT u1.ID as sendTo, u2.ID as sendFrom, messages.message, .....
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....
) as messages;
```

that MUST BE INSERTED just in the place of `messages` (I haven't tried this yet, but I think is like that. See, the thing is I DuckDuckGo'ed and Googled and found nothing, so I came here)

---

My first question is:
Is there a way to use `ALIAS` for the table `messages` so I don't have to scan it TWICE? So, instead, I just save the above query using `ALIAS` as a table called `messages` and select data from it twice, once in each part of `UNION`.

In addition, the answer to the first question would also be an answer for:
Is there a way to use `ALIAS` to save the `time` selected from the table? (since, again, I am searching for it TWICE).

---

In practice, what I am doing may not be unefficient (since there will be at most 20 users), but what if?
Also, I am a mathematician, and like it or not, I like to worry a lot about efficiency!

Thank you so much in advance, I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Why do you need to detect keypresses, what is the task? Also, you seem to be using MySQL - if yes, you may want to add the specific tag to your question.

Comment: which database are you using ?

Comment: can the "keypress" row be outside the latest 30 rows ?

Comment: on your selection of `time` you might want to use `MAX(time)` instead of `LIMIT 1`

Comment: Why not just create a view in place of the long query? Depending on your indexes searching the tables twice could be more efficient than once anyway. You could use a variable to store the time from the User table, but if you have an index on Username, the time taken should be insignificant to the overall performance of the query. Also, if you worry about efficiency don't use `SELECT *`, explicitly list the columns you want, this is more efficient than returning data you are not interested in.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. ianeister, Ian Kenney: actually I AM using SQLite, since I AM building everything locally (Apache) and in's much easier to see the data (I think so, at least, since I AM using sqliteman for Linux and MySQL must be done from terminal).

Comment: Again to Ian Kenney: Yes, it could. Let me explain: When a key is pressed, a particular message is sent (something like an md5). When another user receives that code, it knows that is because of a keypress. It could happen that the keypress is outside of the last 30 rows if I had a huge ammount of connected users chatting. Why, is there a problem?

Comment: Angelo Neuschitzer, thanks for your suggestion, but I think one of us is misunderstanding the other. Intuitively (and since I'm new at this), `LIMIT 1` is a way to tell the DB that, once a username is found, it can stop. Imagine searching on StackOverflow... if you find a username with that name, you may stop.
So, what is the main purpose of MAX(time) in your suggestion, then?
Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question, since I consider what people might be looking for is a [VIEW](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html).

First, define that query like this:

```
CREATE VIEW MyViewTable
AS
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    ...
...;
```

Now you can use that view (which is a sepparate query) in any context where an ordinary table can be used: in a FROM clause, in a JOIN clause, as a subquery etc.:

```
SELECT  ...
FROM MyViewTable
    WHERE ...
    ...

UNION

SELECT ...
    FROM MyViewTable
    WHERE ...
```

but with a few restrictions:

- You **cannot** `SELECT` from your view using subqueries, such as

  ```
   SELECT * FROM MyViewTable WHERE someColumn = (SELECT ... ...)
  ```

  *but* (as normal) you can use subqueries when creating the `VIEW` and in the main query.
- The SELECT statement **cannot** refer to prepared statement parameters.
- The definition **cannot** refer to a TEMPORARY table, and you cannot create a TEMPORARY view.

(there are more, but this are, in my opinion, among the most common queries, so the restrictions might be among the most common errors. See [SQLite reference](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_createview.html) for more information. ).

Comment: The restrictions are taken from the MySQL manual, correct? The first one is interpreted incorrectly: it is the *view's SELECT* that cannot have any subqueries. A query that *uses* the view, [*can* have subqueries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74134/1). However, what's more important is that the restriction [doesn't appear to apply to SQLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/23153/1). As for the other two, even if they apply to SQLite, I think they are irrelevant to your problem. Anyway, thanks for posting your own answer. Please consider expanding on your own solution too if you think it's worth sharing.

Comment: That's correct, they come from MySQL manual, but they apply too to SQLite, since I tried it yesterday. The other two were taken from SQLite reference. I'm editing now. Sorry for all the trouble I'm causing you...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but it does look as if you want a [view](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html).

Define that query like this:

```
CREATE VIEW MyMessageView
AS
SELECT ...
FROM ...
...
```

Now you can use that view in any context where an ordinary table can be used: in a FROM clause, in a JOIN clause, as a subquery etc.:

```
SELECT  ...
FROM MyMessageView
WHERE ...
...
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM MyMessageView
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, a view might help, though I need to check whether `PHP PDO` supports multiple queries in the same execution...  Also, I have been reading and what it does is it creates some sort of temporary table (by the way, I like it more here: [SQL CREATE VIEW](http://bit.ly/12enKxQ)). So, if I execute in two queries, that `VIEW` should persist on the second query, is that right? Otherwise I'm like at the beginning... Thank you very much, I love your answer!

Comment: Yes! Got what I wanted in three queries. Now comes the question... is in more unefficient than simply copying the whole block twice inside the query? (that is, using the same query twice). I know SQLite is a file, but... how slow/fast for MySQL executing two consecutive queries? (Don't answer, I'm sure somebody has asked already)

Comment: Sorry, wasn't around to respond in time. I don't know much about SQLite but as for other major SQL products, a view is primarily a query saved and assigned a name. By default it is not a persisted dataset. Some products support *materialised views* as a separate concept from (normal) views, and I don't know whether SQLite has a similar concept or it treats common views as materialised ones under certain circumstances (or neither). Sorry if this turns out not what you really expected and in that case, please feel free to uncheck the accept mark on my answer. (That would only be fair, I reckon.)

Comment: Well, I checked your answer because, since SO is some sort of knowledge wiki, your answer might be the best for a person looking for the same answer as I. But, anyway, I solved my problem without using the `UNION` statement, since I was limiting erroneously some results (in a very active chat, there could be more than 30 messages per second sent!) and now I get all keypresses and all messages, so I could fit it in just one statement. As I said, your question is marked because it might be the answer people are looking for.

Comment: With all due respect, I'm reverting your edit. I perfectly appreciate your desire to help and improve but I think your change is adding confusion. For one thing, your question is about SQLite and your addition to my answer is referencing a manual page from MySQL. What did you mean by that? Other things, like "frozen table" seem dubious to me and I'm not sure I'll be able to answer people asking me about the meaning of that. I'm sorry, I don't mean to offend you. Please post your own answer about the solution you've ended up with, including, if necessary, your thoughts on views as you see fit.

Comment: I'm not at all offended, I realize I shouldn't have done that. I will post my own answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using UNION, put an OR in the condition:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE time > (SELECT time FROM users 
                  WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1)
        AND (message <> '$keypressCode' AND sendTo = '$username'
             OR message = '$keypressCode')
```

Comment: This probably won't work, it looks like the idea of the UNION is to get 30 messages where `message <> '$keypressCode'` and only 1 where `message = '$keypressCode'`, i.e. 31 in total. If you use or there is no way to guarantee of the 31 returned the split will be 30-1 as required.

Comment: As GarethD says, I don't think this suits me. See, the idea is to get, from all the messages sent on the past 2 seconds, a table containing the last 5 keypresses from all the users (which, by the way the JS is programmed, makes it possible to be only 1 per user in that time interval) and all the messages. So one of the conditions must have a `LIMIT 5` or whatever, independently from the condition to search all messages.

Of course, my idea was to create an `ALIAS` for the `messages` table, so I did not have to `JOIN` twice.

Any suggestions, somebody, please?

Thank you very much anyway!!

Comment: Please don't combine `AND` and `OR` in the same clause without parentheses... you and I know the rule, but someone else might not, and it just confuses things.